# LWC Quick Action component can be opened as a modal on click of a lightning-button

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-design-system

I have a lwc modal component which opens on a quick action in Account object. Can I call that component using a custom lightning-button from another custom lwc component in Account lightning record page?

Comment: Why not drop it in a flow screen and use a flow quick action?